# Getting DataProc output in GCP Logging

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, google-cloud-logging

I have a DataProc job that outputs some logs during the execution. I can see those logs in the Job output.

My cluster is created according to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/logging#job_logs_in) with such parameters:

```
dataproc:jobs.file-backed-output.enable=true
dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable=true
dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable=true
dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.yarn.container.enable=true
```

I can see all system logs in Logging, but not the output from my job. The maximum I found is the URL to the rolling output file (even not a concrete file).

Is there any chance I can forward job output to Logging?

As per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/guides/driver-output) cluster can be created with spark:spark.submit.deployMode=cluster so the output will be logged into yarn user logs group. But whenever I do that my job is failing with:

```
21/03/15 16:20:16 ERROR org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context!
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a cluster and submit jobs as follows.
I went to StackDriver and refreshed my page.
After refreshing, I could see `Cloud Dataproc Job` logging filter.

Also I noticed that both the jobs I ran, the job output was logged as 'Any Log Level'. Not sure if you are using any log level filtering.

Are you able to see `Cloud Dataproc Job` in logging filter after passing `dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable=true` and refreshing the page?

Are you using one of the supported image versions?

Repro steps:
Cluster Creation:

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create log-exp --region=us-central1 \
--properties 'dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.job.driver.enable=true'
```

Job Submisson: PySpark

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark \
    gs://dataproc-examples/pyspark/hello-world/hello-world.py \
    --cluster=log-exp  \
    --region=us-central1
```

Job Submission: Spark

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark \
    --cluster=log-exp \
    --region=us-central1 \
    --class=org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --jars=file:///usr/lib/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples.jar \
    -- 100
```

[Cloud Dataproc Job filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gb4Cn.png)
[Loggin level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fjn51.png)